# ArcPy replacing network mapped drive with UNC

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, data-source, syntaxerror

[image]I am writing a script in Python to look in the current MXD for paths which are on a mapped network drive instead of the UNC path to the network.
However I am getting a syntax error. I am not very versed in Python.

How can I fix this script?

```py
import arcpy
mxd= arcpy.mapping.MapDocument 
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd): 
    if lyr.supports("DATASOURCE"): 
        if r"company shared data" in lyr.datasource.lower(): 
            lyr.findAndReplaceWorkspacePath(r"S:",r"\\network.local\company shared data") 
mxd.saveACopy(r"\\network.local\company shared data\Scientific Data\ArcGIS\MXD")
del mxd
```

Comment: There's a difference between a script and the text pasted in the interpreter.  Please eliminate the noise from the interpreter by pasting the code into a `.py` file., then run that. This will give a line number for your error.

Comment: Hi Vince, thanks for the reply. That is just me getting used to this site. My syntax error is on line 5. I've edited the question to look like my code block

Comment: You can choose any indent scheme you want, so long as you want four spaces. UNC paths have a leading double slash. The code you have here has incorrect indentation.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, that was an edit to the code for upload here to remove my company's internal network name. Is the only problem here with this code the indentation then? It is giving me the error 'Parsing error SyntaxError: invalid syntax (line 5)' and will not run

Comment: We have no way to know what other errors might exist with the errors being masked by copy/paste failure.  I've repaired your indent errors, but you still have **two** incorrect `findAndReplaceWorkspacePath` requests, and faulty logic in replacing the S: if it's not present.

Comment: I have added a photo in hopes this helps! Thank you

Comment: Vince, is there a way to replace any mapped network path instead of hardcoding to S drive. My theory here was to replace S with any mapped netowork drive my users are linking to and have several scripts because I did not know the logic that would traverse an A-Z mapped network drive possibility.

Comment: You should be testing for `lyr.datasource.startswith('S:')` and replacing `r'S:\'` with `r'\\network.local\'`

Comment: Sometimes a raw string ending in a backslash doesn't translate correctly. You can use `'S:\\'` instead

Comment: Please always provide code as formatted text rather than pictures.

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed that in the screenshot of your code, you have the following in line 5:

`if r"company shared data\" in layer.datasource.lower():`

The backslash right before your closing quotation will escape that quotation mark and make it part of the string, so it continues searching for the next **non-escaped** quotation mark to close the string. This effectively makes your test string '`company shared data" in lyr.datasource.lower(): lyr.findAndReplaceWorkspacePath(r`' rather than '`company shared data`'. This leaves an orphan `"` in the remainder of your line 5 since now there are an odd number of `"` and you get a syntax error. This is because all non-escaped `"` all need a second `"` to terminate the designation of each string.

However, I did notice you corrected this error in the typed code block in your question. Make sure to rerun this code with that change.